# JEE - JTA transaction never rollback when throw exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, rollback, jta

I have a JEE aplicacation that runs in tomEE plume 7.1.0.
I try to rollback a simple transaction throwing a RuntimeException, but changes are always made in the database.
When I execute eliminarUsuarios() from EditarUsuarioBean always delete registers from database.

**persistence.xml**

```
<persistence-unit name="XinsPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/xins</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

**DataSource**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/xins" 
          auth="Container" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 

          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xins" 
          username="root" 
          password="root" 

          maxTotal="100" 
          maxIdle="20" 
          minIdle="5" 
          maxWaitMillis="10000"/>
```

**Stateful Bean**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class EditarUsuarioBean {

    @Inject
    private UsuarioServicio servicio;

    public String eliminarUsuarios(){
        try{
            servicio.eliminarUsuarios()
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
```

**Stateless Bean**

```
@Stateless
public class UsuarioServicio {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "XinsPU")
    private EntityManager em;


    public List<Usuario> listado() throws Exception{
        Query consulta = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Usuario u");
        return consulta.getResultList();
    }

    //Never rollback transaction. With or without @Transactional anotation
    //@Transactional( rollbackOn={MiExcepcion.class } )
    public boolean eliminarUsuarios() throws Excepcion{                        
        List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = listado();                
        for(Usuario u : listaUsuarios){
            em.remove(u);
        }                
        em.flush();     

        throw new MiExcepcion();

        return true;
    }
```

**Exception**

```
@ApplicationException(rollback=true)
public class MiExcepcion extends RuntimeException {
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the Transactional annotation? container managed EJB public methods are transactional by default.

Comment: Never rollback transaction. With or without @Transactional anotation

Comment: Weird. This reads like auto-commit is somehow happening. But that should be impossible in container managed transactions. Second experiment: your exception is actually not a RuntimeException but a regular checked exception. What if you let it extend from RuntimeException, which by definition should cause a rollback to be triggered?

Comment: You should not mix CDI and EJB if you are not aware of the implications (which are quite complex).

Comment: I have modified MiExcepcion to extend from RuntimeException but still without rollback transaction, I add jtaManaged='true' to Resource but nothing changes, I try calling context.setRollbackOnly() but no rollback.... Frito: I only try to rollback a transaction using jta and container managed transaction... What am I mixing?

Comment: Which ORM do you use?

Comment: Eclipselink integrated in tommEE plume 7.1.0

Comment: Remove @Transactional annotation

Comment: Never rollback transaction. With or without @Transactional anotation